# VBScript - check if firewall is enabled

Tags: windows, vbscript, firewall

I wrote a script to check on Windows if firewall is enabled. It looks fine but it always says that firewall is enabled - even if it is disabled. I spend a lot of time analysing it with no result - can you possibly help me figure out what is wrong with it?

```
Dim strFirewallStatus, strComputer
strComputer = "localhost"

Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_ 
                       strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

If err.number = 0 Then
  objReg.GetDWORDValue &H80000002, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\" &_
  "Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\" &_
  "DomainProfile\", "EnableFirewall", dwValue

  If dwValue <> 0 Then
    strFirewallStatus = "Firewall is enabled"
  Else
    strFirewallStatus = "Firewall is disabled"
  End If

  WScript.Echo strFirewallStatus
Else
  WScript.Echo strComputer & " - Error" & err.number & " : " &_
  err.description
  err.clear
End if
```

I saved that script as .vbs file.

And by the way - how do I set a script on system startup? I would like this script to add informations to registry automaticly after first launch.

Comment: Here's an alternative that might work for you:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692641.aspx

Comment: Is Windows Firewall currently using your domain profile?  Have you checked (using regedit) that the registry value in question actually changes when you turn the firewall off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider that the Firewall could be enabled/disabled for a `Domain Profile`, for a `Standard Profile (Private or domestic lan)` and for a `Public Profile (public lan)`.
Each setting has a separated key in the registry.

If your PC is not part of a domain the test returns as default value **Enabled**.

On my home PC (win7 64bit no domain) if, instead of **'DomainProfile'**, I use **'StandardProfile'** then the script return correctly the current state of the firewall.

```
If err.number = 0 Then 
  objReg.GetDWORDValue &H80000002, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\" &_ 
  "Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\" &_ 
  "StandardProfile\", "EnableFirewall", dwValue
```